# JS array of objects with an id and name set to Vuetify select :items so that you select a name and it sets the id as the value

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have an array of objects with an id and name:

```
Teams [
    { id: 1, name: 'team1' },
    { id:2, name: 'team2' } 
]
```

Is there a way to pass the names to a vuetify select's items so that when you select a name, you'd set the object's id as the v-model value?:

```
<v-select
  v-model="???"
  :items="???"
  label="Teams"
></v-select>
```

I'm guessing this would be in the created method, but not really sure where to even start. Right now, I am setting an empty teams array to the teams that are in the store on the app's initial fetch:

```
this.teams = this.$store.state.teams.teams
```

I'm getting this as a collection from the laravel backend, so I was contemplating transforming to an id: name key value pair there, but that's seems unnecessary. As it is, I'm just doing the most best eloquent query in the index method of my resource controller:

```
$teams = Team::all();

return response()->json($teams);
```

I know how to do this with a normal select, but not sure with vuetify's v-select:

```
<select id="categories" v-model="selectedValue">
    <option v-for="item in items" :value="item.id">{{ item.name }}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please do it like this:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-select v-model="data" :items="items" label="Teams" item-text="name"
   item-value="id"></v-select>

      <div>
        {{data}}
      </div>
    </v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <script>
    vue = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: () => ({
        data: "",
        items: [{
            id: 1,
            name: 'one'
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            name: 'two'
          }
        ]
      })


    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a million!

Answer (score 4):

you could this by changing your declaration to

```
<v-select
  :items="array-of-objects"
  label="Teams"
  item-text="id"
  item-value="name"
></v-select>
```

as mentioned in the documentation:

> Can be an array of objects or array of strings. When using objects,
>   will look for a text and value field. This can be changed using the
>   item-text and item-value props.

Reference: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects

Basically you are allowed to give a list of objects to :items however they are mandated to be `text` and `value` pairs. The directives `item-text` and `item-value` help you customize it for our use case.

Comment: Thanks a million!